# Sonar pdf report doesn't show Issue details file

Tags: sonarqube

We use Sonar 4.5.1 . The sonar-pdf-plugin is sonar-pdfreport-plugin-1.5-SNAPSHOT . After the sonar pdf report is downloaded from dashboard, we see that 'Issue details' section doesn't display the file name and line number details as shown in screenshot below[image]

Comment: Can someone please reply to this question ?

Comment: The SonarQube PDF Report plugin is a community plugin which is not compatible with the latest 5.6 LTS version of SonarQube. I would suggest you to fill an issue directly in the relating GitHub repository : https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pdf-report